# Custom cache with iterator does not work as intended

Tags: python, caching, python-dataclasses

I got the following class, where:

`iterable` is the passed argument, like for example `range(20)`, `n_max` is an optional value, which limits the numbers of elements the cache should have, `iterator` is a field that gets initiated with the iterable, `cache` is the list I am trying to fill and `finished` is a `bool` which signals if the iterator is "empty" or not. Here is an example input:

```
>>> iterable = range(20)
>>> cachedtuple = CachedTuple(iterable)
>>> print(cachedtuple[0])
0
>>> print(len(cachedtuple.cache))
1
>>> print(cachedtuple[10])
10
>>> print(len(cachedtuple.cache))
11
>>> print(len(cachedtuple))
20
>>> print(len(cachedtuple.cache))
20
>>> print(cachedtuple[25])


@dataclass
class CachedTuple:
    iterable: Iterable = field(init=True)
    n_max: Optional[int] = None
    iterator: Iterator = field(init=False)
    cache: list = field(default_factory=list)
    finished: bool = False

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.iterator = iter(self.iterable)

    def cache_next(self):
        
        if self.n_max and self.n_max <= len(self.cache):
            self.finished = True
        else:
            try:
                nxt = next(self.iterator)
                self.cache.append(nxt)

            except StopIteration:
                self.finished = True


    def __getitem__(self, item: int):

        match item:
            case item if type(item) != int:
                raise IndexError

            case item if item < 0:
                raise IndexError

            case item if self.finished or self.n_max and item > self.n_max:
                raise IndexError(f"Index {item} out of range")

            case item if item >= len(self.cache):
                while item - len(self.cache) >= 0:
                    self.cache_next()

                return self.__getitem__(item)

            case item if item < len(self.cache):
                return self.cache[item]


    def __len__(self):

        while not self.finished:
            self.cache_next()
        return len(self.cache)
```

Although this code is certainly not good, at least it works for almost every scenario, but using the range function of Python for example. If I use for example

```
cachedtuple = CachedTuple(range(20))
for element in cachedtuple:
    print(element)
```

I get the element until `19` and then the program loops infinitely. I think one problem might be that I have no `raise StopIteration` in my code. So I am kind of lost how to fix this mess.

Comment: I must ask, what is the point of the match statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bug is due to these lines:

```
case item if item >= len(self.cache):
    while item - len(self.cache) >= 0:
        self.cache_next()
```

Basically, `CachedTuple((1,2,3))[50]` will loop indefinitely, as `50` is larger than the length of the cache, and `self.cache_next()` won't generate any new values.

A simple change adding a `self.finished` check will work:

```
case item if item >= len(self.cache):
    while item - len(self.cache) >= 0 and not self.finished:
        self.cache_next()
```

I do however believe you have numerous other issues with the code, and I think you can improve it tremendously:

1. Drop the match statement. It does nothing.
2. Implement iteration using `__iter__` instead of relying on the old iteration mechanism of `__getitem__`.
3. Inherit from the `collections.abc.Sequence` and adhere to the `Sequence` protocol.
4. Drop the dataclass. This is not a dataclass. You seem to enjoy the delightful new language features, but unfortunately none of them are relevant and it's causing your code to be longer, less clear, and not working as intended.

Remember, simple readable code is infinitely more important than using new language features.

---

I took the liberty and spent a few hours creating an example code complying to `collections.abc.Sequence`. Enjoy!

```
from collections.abc import Sequence
import itertools
from typing import Iterable, Iterator, Optional, TypeVar, overload

_T_co =TypeVar("_T_co", covariant=True)

class CachedIterable(Sequence[_T_co]):
    def __init__(self, iterable: Iterable[_T_co], *, max_length: int = None) -> None:
        self._cache: list[_T_co] = []
        
        if max_length is not None:
            if max_length <= 0:
                raise ValueError('max_length must be > 0')
            iterable = itertools.islice(iterable, max_length)
        else:
            try:
                # Attempt to optimize and get a length.
                max_length = len(iterable)  # type: ignore
            except TypeError:
                max_length = None

        self._max_length = max_length
        self._iterator: Optional[Iterator] = iter(iterable)
    
    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return (f'<{self.__class__.__name__} {self._cache!r}'
                f'{"+" if self._iterator else ""}>')
    
    def _exhaust_iterator(self) -> None:
        """Fully exhaust the iterator."""
        assert self._iterator
        try:
            self._cache.extend(self._iterator)
        finally:
            self._iterator = None

    def _advance_iterator(self, n: int) -> None:
        """Attempt to advance the iterator by n steps.

        May advance by less than n steps if the iterator is exhausted.
        """
        assert self._iterator
        
        pre_advance_length = len(self._cache)

        try:
            self._cache.extend(itertools.islice(self._iterator, n))
        except Exception:
            # Iterator threw an exception.
            self._iterator = None
            raise

        # If iterator exhausted, clear it.
        if pre_advance_length + n > len(self._cache):
            self._iterator = None
        
    def _grow_cache(self, size: int) -> None:
        """Atttempt grow the cache to be at least size.
        
        May grow to less than size if the iterator is exhausted.
        """
        if size <= len(self._cache):
            return

        if self._max_length and size >= self._max_length:
            self._exhaust_iterator()
            return
        
        self._advance_iterator(size - len(self._cache))
    
    @overload
    def __getitem__(self, i: int) -> _T_co: ...

    @overload
    def __getitem__(self, s: slice) -> Sequence[_T_co]: ...
        
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if not isinstance(index, (slice, int)):
            raise TypeError(f'index must be int or slice, not {index!r}')

        if not self._iterator:
            return self._cache[index]

        if isinstance(index, slice):
            # Stop might be less than start if step is negative.
            max_index = max(index.stop or 0, index.start or 0)
            
            # If we're counting from the end, exaust the iterator.
            if (index.stop is not None and index.stop < 0 or
                    index.start is not None and index.start < 0):
                self._exhaust_iterator()
            
            else:
                self._grow_cache(max_index + 1)

            return self._cache[index]

        # Asking for a number beyond the limit.
        if self._max_length and index > self._max_length:
            raise IndexError(f'index {index} out of range')

        # If we're counting from the end, exaust the iterator.
        if index < 0:
            self._exhaust_iterator()
        else:
            self._grow_cache(index + 1)

        return self._cache[index]
    
    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[_T_co]:
        if not self._iterator:
            yield from self._cache
            return
        
        yield from self._cache
        while True:
            try:
                item = next(self._iterator)
                # Iterator threw an exception.
            except StopIteration:
                self._iterator = None
                return
            except BaseException:
                self._iterator = None
                raise
            
            self._cache.append(item)
            # Prevent capturing GeneratorExit and other gen.throw() exceptions.
            yield item


    def __len__(self) -> int:
        # TODO: Can optimize for known lengths.
        if not self._iterator:
            return len(self._cache)

        self._exhaust_iterator()
        return len(self._cache)
```

Comment: I agree, I was just practicing the features to get a feeling for them, but your advice is greatly appreciated! So this is how the  getitem of the standard list function works? It increases the index until it the index gets "too large" ?

Comment: @kklaw that is correct.